Indy 10 error: "could not load SSL library"
I am using RAD Studio 2010.
I am using Indy as it is when I installed 10.5.5.
I am trying to send an email to Naver or Google mail using TIdSMTP.
When I try to send an email, I get a message saying "could not load SSL library".
I downloaded Indy 10 OpenSSL related DLLs from the Internet and copied libeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll to the executable folder.
I downloaded OpenSSL indy_openssl096.zip, indy_openssl096b.zip, etc and copied them, but I still get the same error message.
I wonder if there is something else to set, or if I received the wrong DLL files.
I'm wondering where to find the OpenSSL library and if I just need to copy it to a folder.

What does Indy's IdSSLOpenSSLHeaders.WhichFailedToLoad() function report after the error has occurred? Where did you download the OpenSSL DLLs from exactly? Use the ones from https://github.com/IndySockets/OpenSSL-Binaries What is the version number of the DLLs you are using? Indy 10 currently supports up to 1.0.2u. The indy_openssl...zip files are meant for Indy 9 not Indy 10.

RAD Studio 2010.
I'm currently writing a program to send files via Google Mail.
I am writing a program with IdSMTP1, IdMessage1,IdSSLIOHandlerScoketOpenSSL1.
I downloaded the openssl-1.0.2u-x64_86-win64.zip file for authentication and copied it to the executable folder.
What values ​​should I check or get using openssl.exe?
I don't know what to do with openssl.exe, so I am asking for help.
And, is it okay to leave
certFile, CipherList,KeyFile blank in
IdSSLIOHandlerScoketOpenSSL1->SSLOptions?
Please provide an explanation or related materials.
Thank you for reading.

You didn't answer my question about WhichFailedToLoad(). Also, you can't use openssl.exe with Indy, and it won't help you troubleshoot anyway. All you need is the 2 DLLs.

IdSSLOpenSSLHeaders component is not visible.
If you copy only ssleay32.dll,libeay32.dll to the execution folder,
If you look at the IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1 component,
There are certfile,cipherlist,keyfile in ssloptions. Do you not need to set these values?

IdSSLOpenSSLHeaders is a unit, not a component. Add #include <IdSSLOpenSSLHeaders.hpp> to your code. WhichFailedToLoad() is a standalone public function in that unit. Don't worry about the SSLIOHandler's properties right now, they have nothing to do with the load error. Fix the load error first, then post a new question later about the SSLIOHandler properties if needed.

Now I'm getting a "Connection Closed Gracefully" error.
Even if I do IdSMTP1->CheckForGracefulDisconnect(true);
it's the same.

You should not be calling
CheckForGracefulDisconnect() directly. Only Connect(), Send(), Disconnect(). Are you still getting the OpenSSL load error? That is the only thing you should be focused on for the purpose of this question post. If you are having other issues, those need to be addressed separately.
